# How to integrate MailChimp API in Bootstrap contact form

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've used this [tutorial](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form) to build a contact form using the Bootstrap framework. However, with literally no knowledge of PHP, I'm having difficulty implementing a MailChimp API with validation. I've found a MailChimp API [tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/add-subscriber-to-list-mailchimp-api-php/), but am not able to get the validation working. Can anybody help me adjust the contact.php file indicated in tutorial 1 to get the API working with validation?

Comment: in that bootstrapious tutorial they're using [native `mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), is there any reason why you prefer to use MailChimp? I'm asking this because not only code is involved here, so would need to know about MailChimp configurations.

Comment: I would prefer to not have to manually update my mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

The second tutorial you've provided was working just fine for me. What kind of validation were you referring to?
First, I just took API key and list ID as described and created the two php files provided. Second, I edited the action.php and changed line 9 and 10, replacing the string for my own.

When you integrate it into your bootstrap page, make sure to change the ending of the file from html to php.